# People Picker loses data

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

I have made 3 tabs in an aspx page using asp.net multiview control with menu control.  I have 2 people editor controls in the 1st tab and the 3rd tab.  When I enter my username name in first tab and go back to third tab and again come to first tab the people picker loses value.

How can I retain the values in the peoplepicker?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe the multiview control does not keep its state when changing view. You may try either with Ajaxcontrol toolkit's tab control, or a pure client side jQuery's Tab plugin (I use this plugin a lot in my sharepoint apps).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of hiddenfields if you don't mind using it, take 2 hiddenfields along with your 2 people editor controls.
When tab is changed, set value of people editor in specific hidden field, and in page load check for both the hiddenfields value, if hidden field is not null, set hidden field value in specific people editor.

Thanks.